# What are some options for syntax for async/await?

Tags: syntax, language-design, async

Some languages, such as JS and Rust, make a distinction between normal/synchronous functions and `async` ones. An `async` function is typically syntax sugar for one which returns a future/promise, which like the name implies, will (theoretically) have a value at some point in the future. In order to get a value from this promise without using a callback function, one can `await` it. An `await` can only be used in an `async` function, and it will "block" (typically allowing other things to run in the thread) until the promise returns.

Both JS and Rust use an `async` keyword in front of the function keyword to make a function asynchronous. While JS uses a prefix `await` operator, Rust uses a postfix `.await` which looks like a property access. I've seen complains about both syntaxes, many of which I agree with.

What are some different options for `async`/`await` syntax, and what are their pros and cons?

Comment: The answers so far focus on `await`, but I’m curious about `async` as well — JS `async function foo()` vs Swift `func foo() async`, for example.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Ooh I've never seen postfix `async` before, it's worth making that an answer I think

Answer (score 9):

## Prefix `await` operator

**Used by:**

- JavaScript
- Python

**Pros:**

(None)

**Cons:**

- Can be ambiguous with an identifier (e.g., since JS added this in after the fact, the error message for `await` in a non-`async` function is incredibly cryptic to maintain backwards compatibility)
- Ambiguous what it's applying to, requiring parentheses (is `await y().z()` `await`ing `y()` or `.z()`?)
- Reads out of order (`await (await fetch(...)).body()`)

## Postfix `.await` property/operator

**Used by:**

- Rust

**Pros:**

- Reads in the same order as methods (`.post().await.to_string()`)
- Distinct from other methods due to lack of `()`

**Cons:**

- Looks like a struct/object property instead of an operator

## Postfix `.await()` method/operator

**Used by:**

(Nothing?)

**Pros:**

- Reads in the same order as methods

**Cons:**

- Looks like an ordinary method, rather than one which has a special meaning

## Implied `await`

Implied `await` would be a system where a promise/future returned by a function would, by default, be `await`ed, with some sort of operator being used to force it to return a promise. This operator could even work on non-`async` functions, meaning that the interface with a function stays identical regardless of whether or not it's `async`, removing the need to go through and add `await` to every instance of a function call.

**Used by:**

- Kotlin (although `async` is called `suspend` there)

**Pros:**

- Saves clutter
- Interface with a function is the same regardless of whether it's `async`

**Cons:**

- Could cause confusion?

Comment: Swift uses prefix await, but avoids the parentheses issue by letting you “factor it out”: Instead of `await (await x()).y()`, you can just say `await x().y()`.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Ooh, interesting. Maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: Just added it to my existing answer.

Comment: “Looks like an ordinary method, rather than one which has a special meaning” isn’t the the whole point? Many methods are special in many languages

Comment: I would put a pro in "prefix await operator": since it's used by many big languages it's more common than the alternatives.

Implicit `await` can be ambiguous (do I want to pass the promise or the value? We could do based on type, but what if it's a generic?)

Comment: re: properties/methods - note that that's trivially solved by highlighting. also parentheses being (mostly) optional is an advantage of postfix `await`

Comment: @tarzh Implicit await isn't ambiguous. The rule is simple: you don't look inside until you need the value. If you need to know the runtime type, that's looking at the value, so you await. If you pass it to a function in the same language, if it's not a generic, you just pass it along, until something awaits.

Then you keep on passing it along. If you pass it to a foreign function, you extrac the value, awaiting if needed, unless the ff is declared to take a future/promise/awaitable

Downside is awaiting is invisible.

Comment: I'd want my IDE to higlight all potential  await points. Sometimes you need to know, particularly when it's a single-threaded environment (ie. JS) and  you typically depend on a guarantee no other task will be executing.

Comment: @BobKerns indeed, IntelliJ automatically highlights all functions calls that could `suspend`

Answer (score 7):

To add to [rssh's answer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/658/504), the need for special syntax for async/await derives from a lack of a general effect system.
Effect-aware languages such as Koka encode effects in function types and have `async` be an user-defined effect.
In Koka, such a function may be written

```
effect async
    fun await(f: (a -> io ()) -> io ()): a

fun sleep(d: duration): async ()
    await fn(cb) {
        set-timeout(cb, d.milliseconds)
    }

fun f(): async int
    sleep(2.ms)
    42
```

See [Structured Asynchrony with Algebraic Effects](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/asynceffects-msr-tr-2017-21.pdf), Daan Leijen, 2017, and [Koka's `async`/`await` implementation](https://github.com/koka-lang/koka/blob/v1-master/lib/std/async.kk).

Other languages in this category include [Eff](https://www.eff-lang.org/), [Effekt](https://effekt-lang.org/), [Ante](https://antelang.org/), [Granule](https://granule-project.github.io/), and [Unison](https://www.unison-lang.org/), among others.

As far as syntax go, some of the ones used by those languages are

- `a -> b c` as in `int -> async string`
- `a -{b}> c` as in `int -{async}> string`
- `a -> '{a} c` as in `int -> '{async} string`

Answer (score 4):

## Distinction between asynchronous functions and Tasks/Futures/Promises

This is what Swift does. Asynchronous functions are ***not*** distinguished by returning a Task, as in many other languages. Rather, `async` is an intrinsic part of the function, and you can even overload on it — `foo()` and `await foo()` could do different things, and both or neither of these could return Tasks.

A major advantage to this is that it allows asynchronicity to apply at the level of the entire expression, rather than just a single method call. Instead of having to say `await (await x()).y()`, one can just write `await x().y()`.

The only way to kick off asynchronous work from synchronous code is to wrap it in a `Task { }`, equivalent to C# `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to previous answers:

1. Automatic coloring via implicit conversions.
   I.e., when we have an implicit conversion from F[X] to X, which is enabled when the result of the async function is used as X and this is 'safe'.  (Safety analysis depends on the type of F[_])

details: one of the modes, supported by dotty-cps-async (user-level implementation of async/await for Scala)
Not very popular - people are afraid to enable it.

2. All is async by default (Ozz, variant of C# used in Singularity)
3. It's more about effects:  representing async computation as a context function which returns result in the direct form.
   (i.e.  DirectContext[F] => A. instead F[A])

Variants were discussed on the Scala contributors forum.
Exists few projects which explore this direction.

4. Computation expressions:  I.e., after async, we have expression language enriched by special constructions (let! binding, await, ...  etc.)
   F#,
5. Using monadic effects DSL instead async functions (close to 4).
   Haskell do-notation

Answer (score 4):

## Postfix `async`

Everything else so far talks about `await`, but what about `async`? Most languages I'm familiar with put it at the front, e.g:

```js
async function foo() {
  // ...
}
```

```csharp
async Task Foo()
{
  // ...
}
```

However, Swift puts it at the end:

```swift
func foo() async {
  // ...
}
```

My understanding is that this is to mirror the syntax of throws/try:

```swift
func foo() async {}
func bar() throws {}
func baz() async throws {}

await foo()
try bar()
try await baz()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Deferred `await`

A system can be constructed such that if the actual value of the future/promise is needed (e.g. for addition or printing, but not for purely structural operations), there's an implied `await`. An explicit `await` is probably needed too, but will be much less frequent.

Answer (score 3):

A language sketch I once made, had await-by-default. That is, the expression `f(x)` was equivalent to `await f(x)` in languages like Python and JavaScript. In order to not await, there was special syntax, `f!(x)` which would call `f` but not await its return value.

A major downside for this is that this requires the entire language to be built around async/await semantics. Effectively, every function is an async function. Presumably, this would be hard to implement efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

## No special syntax

In this case, `async`/`await` is just a normal function call.

This is an option for languages with coroutines. This includes Go and Lua, but may also work for any language with generators (e.g. C#, Rust, and Python).

An example of such an implementation is at https://github.com/ms-jpq/lua-async-await

```lua
local a = require "async", async = a.sync, await = a.wait, await_all = a.wait_all

local do_thing = async(function (val)
  local o = await(async_func())
  return o + val
end)

local main = async(function ()
  local thing = await(do_thing())

  local x = await(async_func())
  local y, z = await_all{async_func(), async_func()}
end)

main()
```